# Parse saved xml from table MSSQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-namespaces

I have a table with a column named `xml`. Table is text type but contains xml responses. I need 2 values from this column:

- `PL81300032102` from `<ie801:Traderid>`
- `Some Company sp. z o.o.` from `<ie801:TraderName>`.

It is possible in SQL Server using a query?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EMCSToTrader xmlns="urn:publicid:-:PL:GOV:MF:EMCS:PHASE3:EMCS-TRADER:REQUEST:V1.00" xmlns:ie801="urn:publicid:-:EC:DGTAXUD:EMCS:PHASE3:IE801:V1.51" xmlns:tms="urn:publicid:-:EC:DGTAXUD:EMCS:PHASE3:TMS:V1.51" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Message><ie801:IE801>
<ie801:Header>
  <tms:MessageSender>NDEA.PL</tms:MessageSender>
  <tms:MessageRecipient>PL61300032004</tms:MessageRecipient>
  <tms:DateOfPreparation>2018-07-17</tms:DateOfPreparation>
  <tms:TimeOfPreparation>11:16:44.631</tms:TimeOfPreparation>
  <tms:MessageIdentifier>PL#IE801#69474394</tms:MessageIdentifier>
</ie801:Header>
<ie801:Body>
  <ie801:EADContainer>
    <ie801:ConsigneeTrader language="pl">
      <ie801:Traderid>PL81300032102</ie801:Traderid>
      <ie801:TraderName>Some Company sp. z o.o.</ie801:TraderName> <...>
```

Table structure:

[image: Screenshot of table structure]

I was able to convert text data to xml type using:

```
SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (
    SELECT CAST([xml] AS XML) AS xmlcontent 
    FROM [emcskomunikaty]
) det
```

Now trying to get value from xml.

Comment: Why are you using `text`? That has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. You should really be using the `xml` datatype to store xml.

Comment: Yes, and they are well documented. There's even an `xml` type. They were added back in 2005. Simply googling for `SQL Server xml` returns [the XML Data doc chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), with explanations, how-to's, examples, references.  Do you have a specific question? documentation?

Comment: Its not my idea to use text. I just only get some values from existing database.

Comment: What is the table's schema? What is the type of the `xml` column? *nvarchar* or *xml*? If it's xml you can use the XML functions directly. If not, you need to use `OPENXML(thatColumn)` to parse it and apply functions like `query()` or `value()`. Check the [Retrieve and Query XML Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/retrieve-and-query-xml-data?view=sql-server-2017) for examples

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos This column named xml is type text. I tried this query: select * from 
(select 
       pref.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as RoleName
from 
       [emcskomunikaty] CROSS APPLY
       Roles.nodes('/Body/FirstTransporterTrade') AS Roles(pref)
)  as Result but i have error:"The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml."

Comment: I added new column xml_new as type xml & when tried to convert using this query: [code]insert into emcskomunikaty(xml)
select CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), xml))  from emcskomunikaty;[code]
I've got error: Operand type clash: xml is incompatible with text

Comment: @miszczu update your question with the schema (the CREATE TABLE statement), the query and the error you got. The error explains what's wrong though - you can't apply `nodes` or `query` directly on a text field. If it's well-formed you can cast it to xml, eg `cast( xml as XML)`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can do this:

```
SELECT
    xmldata.value('declare namespace ns1="urn:publicid:-:EC:DGTAXUD:EMCS:PHASE3:IE801:V1.51"; (//ns1:Traderid)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Traderid,
    xmldata.value('declare namespace ns1="urn:publicid:-:EC:DGTAXUD:EMCS:PHASE3:IE801:V1.51"; (//ns1:TraderName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS TraderName
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(xml AS XML)) AS CA(xmldata)
```

The only tricky part here is handling the namespaces. If you choose ignore namespaces then just use `//*:Traderid`.

Comment: Your solution is that what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for patience. One more question: How do I get selected key, eg: in columns I have more than 1 TraderName & If I  tried  xmldata.value('(/Body/EADContainer/ConsigneeTrader /TraderName/*:TraderName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Firma i got nothing (NULL)

Comment: Could you post sample XML (one with many traders) in your question?

Comment: Sample file https://pastebin.com/phGJHC4Y  I need this value: UAB "BRUST from key <ie801:TraderName>

Comment: You want all trader names in separate rows?

Comment: No, enough this one, from <ie801:FirstTransporterTrader

Comment: Ah... it is just a namespace issue. `(//*:FirstTransporterTrader/*:TraderName)[1]` seems to work for your paste. Basically You need to use namespace prefix inside the entire path (wherever you had a : in your original xml). Wrong: `(//Body/EADContainer/ConsigneeTrader//TraderName)[1]` Right: `(//*:Body/*:EADContainer/*:ConsigneeTrader//*:TraderName)[1]`